# Rest assured API showing null response, whenever i try to execute API

Tags: java, api, testing, automation

Below are the code snippet and please give me some help on this

```
@Test
public void VerifyCountries(){
```

//=========================================================================================================================
        // Create a Gson builder object

```
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    Country[] country;

    String url = com.Tecksystem_demo_Utility.URL.FixUrl+EndPointURL.country.getResourcePath();

      response= Webservices.Get(url);
```

====================================================================
Webservices method

```
public static Response Get(String uRI){
    RequestSpecification requestSpecification = RestAssured.given();
    requestSpecification.contentType(ContentType.JSON);
    Response response = requestSpecification.get(uRI);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, what are the conditions and most importantly what is the question here ?

Comment: Bro, Actually i got one API ie http://services.groupkt.com/state/get/USA/all and Question is i need to fetch the data from get method of api, when i am using String url = com.Tecksystem_demo_Utility.URL.FixUrl+EndPointURL.country.getResourcePath();
  response= Webservices.Get(url);
  System.out.println(response.getBody().asString());                   Response showing null and Also

Comment: create a program that returns both largest city and capital based on user input for state name or state abbreviation.

Comment: Will get back to you in some time.

Comment: let res = {
    "RestResponse": {
      "messages": ["Total [249] records found."],
      "result": [{
        "name": "Afghanistan",
        "alpha2_code": "AF",
        "alpha3_code": "AFG"
      }                                  let search = 'afg';

  let result = res.RestResponse.result.filter((res) => {
    return res.alpha3_code.toLowerCase() === search.toLowerCase();
  });

  result.map((res) => {
    console.log(res.name);
  }); These are the HTML logic behind get method

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code snippet which will get the work done using Gson and RestAssured Libraries. Hope this helped for what you are looking for :

```
public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        Response response = given().
                baseUri("http://services.groupkt.com/state/get/USA/all").get();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(getLargestCityAndCapital(sc.nextLine(), response.getBody().asString()));
    }

    private static String getLargestCityAndCapital(String searchState, String responseBody) {
        JsonObject resultData = getJsonObjectFromJsonLevelOne("RestResponse", responseBody);
        JsonArray jArray = getJsonArrayFromJsonElement("result", resultData);
        for(int i = 0; i < jArray.size(); i++) {
            JsonObject jobj1 = jArray.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
            String StateName = jobj1.get("name").getAsString();
            String StateAbbr = jobj1.get("abbr").getAsString();
            if(searchState.equalsIgnoreCase(StateName) || searchState.equalsIgnoreCase(StateAbbr)) {
                String largestCity = jobj1.get("largest_city").getAsString();
                String capital = jobj1.get("capital").getAsString();
                return("Largest City is : " + largestCity + " and Capital is : " + capital);
            }
        }
        return ("No such city found.");
    }

    private static JsonObject getJsonObjectFromJsonLevelOne(String jsonElementIdentity, String jsonString) {
        JsonObject jobj = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, JsonObject.class);
        return (jobj.get(jsonElementIdentity).getAsJsonObject());
    }

    public static JsonArray getJsonArrayFromJsonElement(String jsonElement, JsonObject jsonObject) {
        JsonArray properties = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray(jsonElement);
        return properties;
    }
}
```

Here is the output for valid case :

```
AL
Largest City is : Birmingham and Capital is : Montgomery
```

And for invalid case :

```
OOPS
No such city found.
```

Comment: Thanks alot @learner8269, Appreciate your value time to my task